# Dual Wireless Connection

Tags: windows-8-preview

I had an old gaming desktop running XP and now I have put the Win 8 Beta on it.
I had an wireless PCI card install that I thought was damaged (XP wouldn't use it even after several driver installs).
To fix this problem I bought a USB network adapter and used it for wireless connection.

Now that I have windows eight installed it has recognized both wireless devices and I am connected to the same network, but two different ways!

Can someone tell me the effect this will have on my internet speed, and how my computer will handle two connections to the same network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your computer will be using only one connection simultaneously.
Usually uses the faster, but I advise you to take out the board with less speed. If the two equal off a your choice.